# Watch Connectivity throwing NSFileReadNoSuchFileError -> ENOENT

Tags: xcode, watch, connectivity, watchos

I am using watch connectivity in my app quite successfully, but sometimes when I start the debugging session all I get in that session is a stream of errors like this one:

```
[WC] -[WCFileStorage enumerateIncomingUserInfosWithBlock:] could not load user info data at path /Users/macbook/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DCAF139C-F0A5-4A8E-BF3D-94DD9EA87131/data/Containers/Data/Application/A9BF6C66-8220-41DB-B3F0-E86D14270499/Documents/Inbox/com.apple.watchconnectivity/62A41456-6929-4ABB-8EAA-4B33DEF76783/UserInfo/4FF81332-056B-40BC-BBE5-BCD764C60AED/userinfo-transfer-object-data due to NSFileReadNoSuchFileError -> ENOENT
```

Is there anything I can take out of this?

Also it's worth knowing that I am using Xcode 9.4.1 and iOS + WatchOS simulators.

Comment: Did you figure out the cause for this error message?